# Find the remainder when divided by $2017$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

> Given $2017$ is a prime number. Let $S=\sum_{k=0}^{k=62} \binom{2014}{k}$. Find the remainder when $S$ is divided by $2017$.

I am unable to simplify the expression for $S$. Need some hints. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to have $2017$ in all the binomial coefficients instead of $2014$?

Answer (score 2):

We use four main ingredients to do this computation:

1. If $p$ is a prime, then $p$ divides $\binom p k $ for all $0<k<p$.
2. Every $0<k<p$ is relatively prime to $p$ so we may multiply and divide by such $k$ at any point in our calculation while dealing modulo $p$ without worrying about dividing by zero.
3. Wilson's theorem: For a prime $p$, $(p-1)!\equiv -1 \pmod p$.
4. $\binom n k +\binom n {k+1}=\binom {n+1} {k+1}  $.

Let us begin by computing $$8S=8\left(\sum_{k=0}^{k=62} \binom{2014}{k}\right)=4\left(\binom{2014}{0}+\binom{2014}{62}+\sum_{k=1}^{k=62}\left[\binom {2014}{k-1}+\binom {2014}{k}\right] \right).$$

Using ingredient 4, this simplifies to $$8S=4\left(\binom{2014}{62}+\sum_{k=0}^{k=62}\binom {2015}{k} \right) $$

Doing this same trick twice more, we arrive at
$$8S=4\binom{2014}{62}+2\binom{2015}{62}+\binom{2016}{62}+\sum_{k=0}^{k=62} \binom{2017}{k}.$$

Since $2017$ is prime, by ingredient $1$, the sum on the right is congruent to $1 \pmod {2017}$.

Trusting in the philosophy that it might be easier to compute three binomial coeffients modulo 2017 rather than $63$ of them, we plod on to get

$$8S \equiv 4\frac{2014!}{62!1952!}+2\frac{2015!}{62!1953!}+\frac{2016!}{62!1954!}  +1\pmod {2017}.$$

Now we use ingredients $2$ and $3$ to get $\frac{1}{1952!} \equiv \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{64} (2017-k)}{-1} \equiv -(64!)\pmod{2017}$. We do a similar thing for $1953$ and $1954$ to get $63!$ and $-(62!)$. Next, $2014!,2015!$ and $2016!$ are equivalent to $\frac{-1}{2},1,-1$ respectively modulo $2017$. So,

$$8S \equiv 4\frac{-(64!)}{(62!)(-2)}+2\frac{(63!)}{(62!)}+\frac{(-1)\cdot -(62!)}{62!}+1 \equiv 2\cdot 64\cdot 63+2\cdot 63+1+1\equiv 8192\pmod{2017}.$$

The end is here! After legally dividing by $8$, we get 
$$S \equiv  1024 \pmod{2017}.$$

And there we have it: If you divide that horrible sum by $2017$, we get a remainder of $1024$. Have a nice day!